# Accounts hacked. Eventually showing a different device

Tags: account-security

I recently made a new Facebook account from my android phone [ver. 6.0.1] and when I checked active sessions, instead of my android device a, Linux desktop was displayed.

Then I checked my Gmail and I found that an unknown Linux device logged in about a week ago in two of my Gmail and then I changed all of my passwords and activated 2-step authentication.

But today when I checked my new Facebook account, it was disabled by Facebook due to breaking their rules. I then checked my old Facebook account and found that the Linux device was also logged in and when I checked active sessions, first it said I am on an android device then as I checked it again, it showed my device is a Linux Desktop and then as I refreshed it again, it switched back to android.

After that I checked my login history on other sites and some of them were showing Linux device instead of android.

What should I do now to secure my accounts and data now?

Comment: Does the login activity logs from Facebook and Gmail show the IP? Do you have a Linux desktop?

Comment: Yes, I can see the ip of linux device which is also different from mine. And I don't have a Linux desktop.

Comment: Pop that unknown IP into here: https://dnslytics.com/  Is the IP close to where you live?

Comment: Yeah its close to my location.

Comment: Then, frankly, it is likely that something you have, even your phone, is showing up as a Linux Desktop. It is unlikely that this is a "hack".

Comment: Can incognito mode be the culprit?

Comment: Actually, that might be it

Comment: Well but as far as I know incognito just don't save any browsing history or cookies then why my ip is changed, even if it was for a small interval. And my facebook account also got blocked even if I just logged in it once. If we assume that the Linux desktop and ip doesn't belong to me instead it is from someone living near me, could there be any chance of hacking now?

Comment: It would be a fantastic coincidence that someone near you also gained access to your accounts. The world is large. I also don't know why your FB account was closed, so that might not be relevant.

Comment: Well thanks for the advice. Anyway, can you suggest me a process or steps to check that my data is safe or not?